# Check if line is empty or contains non pritable characters

Tags: c, character-encoding, char, special-characters

How can i check if line that gets scanned from file is empty or contains non printable character? I have tried using strlen() on result of getline which equals 1 when there is empty line but unprintable characters break this code. How can i do it better?

Comment: Do you mean non printable characters break strlen() ? Or that you don't know how to handle non printables?

Comment: `!*line` and `isprint` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If if is a C code then you can write the corresponding function yourself

```
int isValid( const char *s )
{
    while ( *s && !isgraph( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) ++s;

    return *s != '\0';
}
```

if it is a C++ code and you are using a character array then you can use the following approach

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>

//...

if ( std::all_of( s, s + std::strlen( s ), []( char c ) { return !std::isgraph( c ); } ) )
{
   std::cout << "Invalid string" << std::endl;
}
```

For an object of type `std::string` the check will look similarly

```
if ( std::all_of( s.begin(), s.end(), []( char c ) { return !std::isgraph( c ); } ) )
{
   std::cout << "Invalid string" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this backwards? Doesn't this only print 'Invalid string' if all the characters are invalid?  Surely you want to get invalid string if any of the characters are unprintable...

Comment: @jezza As it follows from the question you need to check whether all characters in a string are unprintable

Comment: question says '...is empty or contains non printable character.' To me, this means the string is invalid if it contains any non printable characters.

Comment: @jezza I am sure if it would be so as you are writing then the author of the question wrote me a comment instead of you.

Comment: Presuming whitespace is fine in this question. Then you might want to use `std::isprint` instead. `std::isgraph` excludes whitespaces. Ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isgraph